# How to create facets in matplotlib in Python like you can in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a plot in ggplot2 (R) that I want to replicate using matplotlib (Python):

```
ggplot(data = sca, aes(x = Total_Value)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~Era) + theme_minimal()
```

How can I recreate this using matplotlib, and additionally, how could I overlay the density plots over one another (color coded) in either language/library?

Thank you.

[image: Attached is the image.]

Comment: Is seaborn FacetGrid an option? E.g. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to recreate ggplot2 facets is using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

```py
pip install seaborn
```

Depending on the plot type, use one of [seaborn's figure-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions):

- **[`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) for relational facets** (scatter, line)
- **[`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) for distribution facets** (hist, kde, ecdf)
- **[`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) for categorical facets** (bar, count, point, strip, swarm, box, boxen, violin)

So for density facets, use [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) with `kind='kde'`:

- Sample data

  ```py
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Era': np.random.choice(range(1960, 2180, 20), 200), 'Total_Value': np.random.random(200)})

  #       Era  Total_Value
  # 0    2140     0.479988
  # 1    2100     0.232373
  # 2    2060     0.801881
  # ..    ...          ...
  # 199  2140     0.823781
  ```
- Set `col='Era'` for a grid

  ```py
  import seaborn as sns
  sns.displot(data=df, kind='kde', x='Total_Value', col='Era', col_wrap=4)
  ```

  [image]
- Set `hue='Era'` for overlays

  ```py
  import seaborn as sns
  sns.displot(data=df, kind='kde', x='Total_Value', hue='Era', palette='Purples')
  ```

  [image]